# C++ multidimensional array member accessor

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, methods, encapsulation, accessor

I have a class that has a large 2 dimensional array in it. It used to be a dynamic array allocated on the heap and now it is statically sized which I prefer.

```
private:
    int fontTextureCoords_[100][7];
```

I had to add the type casting to the the accessor in order to return the array for access outside the class which is currently working okay, but I'm not sure it is safe or the correct way to handle this.

```
public:
inline int **getFontTextureCoords()
{   
    return (int**)fontTextureCoords_;
}
```

Is this safe / the correct way to do this or is there a more preferred method for returning a pointer to a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: This is seriously "currently working OK"?!

Comment: Think on this as well: Why bother making a variable private if you're going to hand off unrestricted access to it via pointer?

Comment: There is a simple way to determine if this is the "correct way to handle this".  Remove the `(int **)` cast -- what error did the compiler give you?  Read it carefully -- the compiler is not joking.

Comment: I thought the same thing. That is why I came to ask here. But it did compile and did pull the correct data out of the table... I was as surprised as you, but it seemed flukey which is why I came to ask and find the correct way of handling it.

Comment: As a general rule, "compiles" != "works", since C++ is built on C, and C is famous for its undefined behaviors (a.k.a. nasal demons...http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Never trust the compiler to catch errors - test the living daylights out of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's *not* the correct way to do that and shouldn't compile. A 2d array is not convertible to a pointer to pointer. You'd have to return a pointer to an array, which is easiest to write using a typedef:

```
using T = int[7];
inline T* getFontTextureCoords() { return fontTextureCoords_; }
```

Although it'd be much better to just return a reference the full array:

```
using T = int[100][7];
inline T& getFontTextureCoords() { return fontTextureCoords_; }
```

You could also just `std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 100>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this diagram shows you the difference between the two types of multi-dimensional array declarations. (Sometime people don't understand this.)

[image]

The first one says `a` is a single block of 100 consecutive 7-`int` chunks, or 700 `ints` total, all together in one piece.

The second says `a` is an array of pointers, where each pointer points to a different chunk of `ints`, scattered all over memory.

The compiler needs to know this, because if you write `a[i][j]` it has to generate totally different code.

Comment: Excellent diagram! It makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Casting an array such as `int fontTextureCoords_[100][7];` to an `int**` is not right. It leads to undefined behavior.

If it is not too much, change `getFontTextureCoords` to:

```
inline int (*getFontTextureCoords()) [7]
{   
    return fontTextureCoords_;
}
```

and use it as:

```
int (*ptr)[7] = getFontTextureCoords();
```

If you have the option of using `std::vector` or `std::array`, it will be better to use them.

Answer (score 0):

There are no multi-dimensional arrays in C/C++. There are only single dimenstional arrays. You can have a single-dimensional array, with every element of it being another single dimensional array. While there seem to be no difference, it is there and is very important.

This is exactly way transitive logic doesn not work. Everybody has gone through it. 'If single-dimensional arrays are passed as a pointer to the first elelement, 2-D arrays should be passed as a pointer to pointer to first element, etc'. But since it is not a two-dimensional array, but array of arrays, the logic can not be applied.

You can reason about it in the following way. Let's say, you have an array of types X.

```
X x[10];
```

How do you access element number 5? Easy -

```
x[5] = 42;
```

But what compiler does when it sees it? It does approximately this:

```
*(&x[0] + 5) = 42;
```

So it takes the address of the first element, and adds 5 to it to get to the address of your 5th element. But what adding 5 means? In bytes, how many bytes should be skipped from address of beginning of the array to arrive at requested memory location? Of course, 5 * sizeof(X). Now, if you have '2-D' array, declared like this:

```
X x[2][3];
```

And you try to work with it through the pointer to pointer:

```
px = (X**)x;
px[3][4] = 42;
```

Remember, to genereate the code for [][], compiler needs to express in the way of *(px + ). And something has to be the size of the array (as elements of your array are arrays). But you need to know array size for this, and as you can see, your px does not have any array size encoded in it. The only size it know is size of X, which is not enough.

Hope it makes sense, and explains why you can't use int** instead of x[][].

Comment: Thanks, that is well explained and quite helpful.